# ASP.NET Web API 2 стэк, как быть?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Я большой поклонник C# и ASP.NET, но так случилось что эта технология меняется без остановки. Наконец-то я решил сделать проект в котором я хотел бы освоить как можно больше нового из мира сегодняшнего ASP.NET MVC и WEB Api 2.

Проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю какой стэк мне испольвать? 
Чем сейчас пользуются ASP.NET разработчики? 
Все статьи и блоги которые я нахожу датируются 2012-2014 годом, а было столько всего нового как в мире .Net так и в вэбе и меня это не может не беспокоить. 
Мои требования  к стэку следующие:

1) Нет сильной зависимости между клиентом и API, я хочу что бы клиент был один проект, а API другой.

2) Тестируемость, как клиента так и бэкэнда.

3) По возможности, использование любой БД, хоть я и люблю MS SQL , мне кажется что в вэбе это иногда слишком, + не хочу привязыватся только Windows хостерам, вроде как у нас тут ASP.NET Core который работает везде.

Понимаю что вопрос размытый и ответы на него сугубо субьективные, но я не знаю в какую сторону двигаться.

Возможно существует какой-нибудь проект в открытом доступе где я бы мог посмотреть как реализовано нечто подобное, но к сожелению, я ничего не могу найти подходящего.

Пример стэка: MS SQL (EF) + WebApi + KnockoutJS + HTML5

Я ищу блоги, проэкты, видео, туториалы, в которых бы я увидел актуальные вещи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Core размыл границу между MVC и Web API и теперь выбирать между ними не приходится, но только на первый взгляд. На деле тот же `Angular2` достаточно плохо совместим с серверным рендеренгом (да и нужно ли?) вот и получается, что
собственно озвученный вами стек волне актуален, за исключением `KnockoutJS` он то как раз из 2014го. Меняем его на `React/Angular2/etc` по вкусу.
Если `singlepage` не нужен то хватит и подхода с серверным рендерингом, к тому же по всей видимости Microsoft не списывает этот подход со счетов так как в ASP.NET Core улучшили возможности `Razor`.

**Не большое предостережение:** 
Преже чем начинать проект на ASP.NET Core стоит обратить внимание на [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap). Secure Web Api "из коробки" будет только к версии **1.0.4** (пока как альтернатива - [openiddict](https://github.com/openiddict))

Comment: Все дело как раз в **Singlepage**, я верю что кнопка "обновить" в браузере лишняя :) Значит буду двигаться в сторону Angular2. Но есть вопрос нуба, а зачем этот **RoadMap**?

Comment: RoadMap - это план развития продукта, в данном случае ASP.NET Core. Релиз был не давно и еще не всю функциональность успели перенести с Web API/MVC (аунтификация, signalR и т.д)

Comment: и последний нубский вопрос, а зачем мне SignalR? Из определения: SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client. Так для этого мы используем Angular2 вроде как? или нам его хватает не полностью?

Comment: SignalR крайне удобен, когда вы хотите оповещать клиента (браузер) о неких событиях на сервере - как самый простой примеров.

Comment: Кстати, SignalR как раз и помогает уменьшить небходимость кнопки "обновить"

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал упомянутый asp.net core, уже многие библиотеки переписаны под него. Для работы с БД ef подойдет замечательно, а бд можете выбрать сами, под требования проекта [список провайдеров](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/index), если интересует nosql решения, то mongoDb так же существует по .net core.
Для авторизации посмотрите на [IdentityServer4](http://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/).Если не нравится asp.net mvc - то [NancyFx](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation).
Для клиента я бы предпочел angular, а т.к. C# вам по нраву, то angular2 будет лучшим выбором, т.к. написан на TypeScript. Если же не понравится angular стоит ознакомится с [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) или же [VueJS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/)
И бэкэнд и фронтэнд тестируется на ура, для .net core рекомендую [xUnit](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html)

Лично мне для логгирования на сервере понравился [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) - логи можно выводить куда угодно, да и с .net core дружит.
Встроенный DI-контейнер в asp.net core меня полностью устраивает, но так же не плох [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)